# How to get Facebook AccessToken?

Tags: android, facebook

I have a Facebook Session.but it is not open. i tried to get AccessToken as follows

```
Session.getActiveSession().getAccessToken();
```

but it does not return any thing.how can i get the AccessToken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, as written in the [official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/), you need to have a `UiLifecycleHelper` that will make sure to create a valid session for every fragment that interacts with the Facebook SDK.

what you should do is override the life cycle methods in your fragment (or activity) and then `Session.getActiveSession()` will return a session if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

You almost never need to extract the actual access token anymore. Any requests to the graph API can be done with the [Request class](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request) and a Session object.